# handling css class names with spaces

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

Hi am working on a Django powered project. The following is a code from my html file (template)

```
{% for l in items  %}

                                <td style="text-align: center"
                                    id="{{m.id}}_{{m.set}}">
                                </td>

{% endfor %}
```

and a JS script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set}}').html('{{a.id}}');
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set}}').addClass('{{ a.size__status }}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

Means the td's class will change based on status column from my DB.

My css:

```
.completed{
    background-color: #4dff4d;
}
```

Some of the status are with spaces (not just like one word as "completed"). Ex: "Not yet started". So when I pass this value, my class property is not working. How to handle this problem? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: It might help if you show the relevant parts of the results model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use spaces in status at all. 
Better idea would be to use `Choices` from [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#choices)
Then you can define the status in your model like this:

```
STATUS = Choices(
    ('completed', 'completed'),
    ('not_yet_started', 'Not yet started')
)
status =  models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=20)
```

The first value of the tuples is stored in the database. The second one you can use to display. You can the access it like this

```
obj.status # gives "not_yet_started"
obj.get_status_display # gives "Not yet stared"
```

### UPDATE:

If you don't want to / can't change the entries in the database there are two possible solutions.

- Javascript:

  `'{{a.status}}'.replace(' ', '_')`
- django model property:

  `def status_name(self):
      return self.status.replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: Ya.. True. But its already existing in my DB as a column with status value with spaces. That's why this trouble

Comment: Hm. Then I would suggest migrating the db. One other option might be to strip the spaces with javascript. Like `'{{a.status}}'.replace(' ', '_')`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change the status names add a property to your model that will generate the proper class name for you:

```
@property
def class_name(self):
    return self.size.status.replace(" ", "_")
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set}}').html('{{a.id}}');
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set}}').addClass('{{ a.class_name }}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry Nima,  I just editted my question. Because the status is from another model  and am getting the value as `size__status`

Comment: Why are there two underscores in the name?

Comment: Hi Nima, actually the two underscores because i need to access a field from another model through the foreign key.